# ActiveMQ Artemis console login failed

Tags: activemq-artemis

I recently upgraded to 2.28.0 from 2.19.1. After the upgrade client applications seems to be able to connect to the broker, but I'm not able to login in to the web admin console.

If I use the incorrect user I see below log:

```
2023-04-11 09:54:21,360 WARN  [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] Login failed due to: User does not exist: admin1
```

If I use an incorrect password I see below log:

```
2023-04-11 09:54:32,148 WARN  [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] Login failed due to: Password does not match for user: admin
```

I don't see any log when the credentials are correct, but in Artemis console, I get an "Invalid login credentials" error.

Here's my `login.config`:

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
      debug=true
      reload=true
      org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
      org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

Here is my `artemis.profile`:

```
ARTEMIS_HOME='/opt/app/artemis'
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE='/opt/app/artemis/artemis_broker'

ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_URI='file:/opt/app/artemis/artemis_broker/'
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI='file:/opt/app/artemis/artemis_broker/etc'

JAVA_ARGS=" -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Xms12G -Xmx12G -XX:+UseG1GC -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
```

UPDATE ::

I put artemis in debug mode - after login getting below error :

```
11:54:30,010 DEBUG [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] role amq doesn't match NO_HAWTIO_ROLE, continuing
11:54:30,010 DEBUG [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] User admin does not have the required role NO_HAWTIO_ROLE
```

Then I tried adding `NO_HAWTIO_ROLE` to exising `amq` - this time login worked but showing blank page.

Comment: How do you know the credentials you're using to log in to the web admin console are actually correct?

Comment: I'm using the same credentials from the client application and the application is able to connect using those. Also if I use incorrect credentials as mentioned above I can see logs for incorrect user or password.

Comment: updated `artemis.profile`

Comment: Is the user you're trying to log-in to the web admin console with in the role `amq`?

Comment: I just put Artemis in debug mode and I see it's failing becasue of role, error I see is :
```11:54:30,010 DEBUG [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] User admin does not have the required role NO_HAWTIO_ROLE``` 
.User has `amq` role, I tried adding `NO_HAWTIO_ROLE` - after this, I'm able to log in but all see a blank page now

Comment: That's why I asked if your user was in the `amq` role. At this point I'm guessing it isn't.

Comment: User does have 'amq' role, in addition to that when i added 'NO_HAWTIO_ROLE' then only login worked. But showing blank page.

Comment: How exactly did you perform your upgrade from 2.19.1 to 2.28.0? If you create a brand new instance of 2.28.0 does the web admin console work for you?

Comment: I tried with brand new instance didn't work.

Comment: That's odd. I just create a new instance of 2.28.0 locally and I was able to log in to the web admin console just fine. Can you elaborate on exactly what you did to create the instance and how you attempted to log-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with below changes:

In `artemis.profile` added below lines

```
HAWTIO_ROLE='amq'
ARTEMIS_ETC_DIR='<PATH>/etc'
```

Looks like in 2.19.1 `HAWTIO_ROLE` was optional and was defaulting to 'amq', after upgrading since it was missing Artemis was giving the below error

```
11:54:30,010 DEBUG [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] User admin does not have the required role NO_HAWTIO_ROLE
```

If no role is mentioned in `artemis.profile` Artemis is defaulting to `NO_HAWTIO_ROLE`. And if the user doesn't have this role it will fail the authorization.

This can be checked in `/<BROKER>/artemis` file.

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help others who have this same problem in the future. Thanks!